# Octopus deploy, I need to deploy all packages up till latest on promotion to QA

Tags: redgate, octopus

Here is the story, I am using RedGate SqlCompare to generate update scripts for my Dev env, each package contains only changes from current Dev version to Latest in source control.
Here is an example:

1. I create a table (package-0.1) -> Deploy to DevDB
2. I add Columns (package-0.2)  -> Deploy to DevDB
3. I renamed some Column (package-0.3) -> Deploy to DevDB

But once I want to promote it to QA it causes me problem because it promotes only latest package-0.3 that contains only part of the changes (renaming of the column)

So I am looking for a way to deploy all the packages prior to current on Promotion if it is possible.

By now I solved that by creating custom package that contains all the change scripts, but is it possible to solve that with Octopus?

Thanks 
Ihor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> each package contains only changes from current Dev version to Latest

The way you do it is going to be painful for you as SQL Compare takes a state based approach. What you want to apply is the migrations based approach. You can see [Alex's post on the difference between two approaches](http://workingwithdevs.com/delivering-databases-migrations-vs-state/).

[SQL Source Control 5](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/entrypage/sql-source-control-beta) will come with a better migrations approach which will work with SQL Compare command line tool and [DLM Automation tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dlm/dlm-automation-suite/). However, beta is closed right now unfortunately but I suggest you to contact the team through the e-mail address provided there.

The other option you have is [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/) which has the pure migrations based approach. You can see [this post on its octopus deploy integration](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/Octopus+Deploy).